# `df' unexpected' checking for diskspace inside a function using a while loop bash script

Tags: bash, rhel

I am getting an issue where if I call this function below, I get the error `line 89: syntax error at line 117: 'df' unexpected`.

If I take the code out of the function it works fine.

Is there any reason for the error above?

This is a bash script on RHEL.

```bash
function testr{
  df -H | grep -vE '^Filesystem|tmpfs|cdrom' | awk '{ print $5 " " $1 }' | while read output;
  do
    usep=$(echo $output | awk '{ print $1}' | cut -d'%' -f1)
    partition=$(echo $output | awk '{ print $2 }')
    (.. Sends alert via mail after)
  done
}
```

Comment: Separate function name and `{` with whitespace(s): `function testr {`. Or even better, use this syntax: `testr() {`

Comment: Please extract a [mcve] first! Your snippet surely has no line 117. As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask]. Further: You really need to read the descriptions of the tags you apply!

Comment: thanks didn't spot that, appreciate it!

Answer (score -1):

Maybe a little easier to read this way?

```
testr_zsh () {
    # This (only) works with zsh.
    for usep partition in $( df -H | awk 'NR>1 && !/tmpfs|cdrom/{print $5,$1}' | sed -n '/%/s/%//p' )
    do
        echo "\$usep: $usep, \$partition: $partition"
    done
}

testr () {
    for fs in  $( df -H | awk 'NR>1 && !/tmpfs|cdrom/{print $5"|"$1}' | sed -n '/%/s/%//p' )
    do
        usep="$(echo "${fs}" | sed 's/|.*//' )"
        partition="$(echo "${fs}" | sed 's/.*|//' )"
        echo "\$usep: $usep, \$partition: $partition"
    done
}
```

On my computer not all lines that pass through the awk filter have `%` in them hence adding the `sed` filter. `zsh` allows two vars in the for loop which is pretty slick.